# ColorPicker in matlab

Tags: matlab, color-picker

I want to get the RGB value of the selected color from ColorPicker in Matlab. For example to display the ColorPicker I use:

```
pp2 = com.mathworks.mlwidgets.graphics.ColorPicker(0,0,'');
[j1,c1]=javacomponent(pp2,[450,260,30,20],gcf);
```

After that, how can I get the selected value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `j1.Value`. That is a [`java.awt.Color`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html), and you can get the `RGB` values with [`j1.Value.getRed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getRed()), [`j1.Value.getGreen()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getGreen()), and [`j1.Value.getBlue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getBlue()). These values are in the range [0, 255].

Another way is to use the [`getRGBComponents()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getComponents(float[])) method:

```
colour = j1.Value.getRGBComponents([]);
```

Here, the values are in the range [0, 1]
(cf. [Converting Java vectors to Matlab arrays](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/converting-java-vectors-to-matlab-arrays))